# How to return Data from any[] in Angular?

Tags: angular

I'm using ngx-select-ex component in Angular (https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-select-ex). 
https://optimistex.github.io/ngx-select-ex/
It's a select with autocomplete.

I need to return data from [items] in my menu select, but with my code my select doesn't allow onkeyup events or click events. I need to return it in type any[].

this is my code who returns data to [items]:

app.component.ts

```
 get listCity() {
        return this._listCity ? this._listCity.map(item => {
          return { id: item.id_city, text: item.name_city }
        }) : [];
 }
```

in my app.component.html

```
<ngx-select  name="id_city" required
   [autoClearSearch]="true"
   [(ngModel)] = "user.id_city"
   [allowClear]="true" 
   [items]="listCity" 
   optionValueField="id"
   optionTextField="text" 
   placeholder="Select..."
   [defaultValue]="doNgxDefault()"
   (typed)="inputTyped('ngx-select', $event)"
   (focus)="doFocus()"
   (blur)="doBlur()"
   (open)="doOpen()"
   (remove)="doRemove($event)"
   (selectionChanges)="doSelectOptions($event)">
</ngx-select>
```

This code is from demo and shows how data should be returned:

```
public items: string[] = ['Amsterdam', 'Antwerp', 'Athens', 'Barcelona',
        'Berlin', 'Birmingham', 'Bradford', 'Bremen', 'Brussels', 'Bucharest',
        'Budapest', 'Cologne', 'Copenhagen', 'Dortmund', 'Dresden', 'Dublin',
        'Düsseldorf', 'Essen', 'Frankfurt', 'Genoa', 'Glasgow', 'Gothenburg',
        'Hamburg', 'Hannover', 'Helsinki', 'Kraków', 'Leeds', 'Leipzig', 'Lisbon',
        'London', 'Madrid', 'Manchester', 'Marseille', 'Milan', 'Munich', 'Málaga',
        'Naples', 'Palermo', 'Paris', 'Poznań', 'Prague', 'Riga', 'Rome',
        'Rotterdam', 'Seville', 'Sheffield', 'Sofia', 'Stockholm', 'Stuttgart',
        'The Hague', 'Turin', 'Valencia', 'Vienna', 'Vilnius', 'Warsaw', 'Wrocław',
        'Zagreb', 'Zaragoza', 'Łódź'];
```

Comment: How does `_listCity` looks like? Is it the same as `items`?

Comment: _listCity are id_city, name_city. With id and text. Two variables.

Answer (score 0):

You should subscribe to your formcontrol or the ngModel Changes (`(ngModelChange)="doSelectOptions($event)"`) on select, find the object based on selected id from cityList and return the selected Obj. below is the snippet that shows how to do it on formControl (`selectControl` is the name of control here) Change:

```
this.selectControl.valueChanges
      .subscribe((subscriptionTypeId: number) => {
        const obj = this.selectItems.find(item => item.id === subscriptionTypeId);
        console.log(
          'subscriptionTypeId', subscriptionTypeId, obj
        );
      });
```

Comment: Is this put on ngOnInit()? I did this: ngOnInit(){
    this.getAllCities();
    this.ngxControl.valueChanges
      .subscribe((subscriptionTypeId: number) => {
        const obj = this._listCity.find(item => item.id_city === subscriptionTypeId);
        console.log(
          'subscriptionTypeId', subscriptionTypeId, obj
        );
      });
  }

Comment: I got this error: ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'find' of undefined

Comment: Yes, it is inn onInit, make sure you do it after you have `listCity` available. actually i made a typo to used `this._listCity` chnage it to your listCity array.

Comment: I put the code inside of ngOnInit and got the same error. ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'find' of undefined. And I have cities in my database.